# Creating new columns with value based on dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I have one dataframe and one dictionary:

```
news = {'Text':['dog ate the apple', 'cat ate the carrot', 'dog drank water'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian']}
news_df = pd.DataFrame(news)


w = {1:['horse', 'dog'], 2:['apple'], 10: ['water', 'melon', 'liquerice']}
```

I would like to create a new column news_df['sum'] that looks into news_df['Text'], check whether any of the dictionary values are available and if 1 or more are in the columns, assigns the sum of the keys. My outcome would be:

```
results = {'Text':['dog ate the apple', 'cat ate the carrot', 'dog drank water'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian'], 'sum' : [3, 0, 11]}
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Any idea how? I am not sure what approach to take? Perhaps turn the dictionary into a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an apply approach:

```
def counts(x): 
   sumcount = 0 
   for k, v in w.items(): 
      for word in v: 
        if word in x: 
           sumcount+=int(k) 
   return sumcount 

news_df.Text.apply(counts)
```

```
                 Text    Source  sum
0   dog ate the apple       NYT    3
1  cat ate the carrot        WP    0
2     dog drank water  Guardian   11
```

Comment: Not sure why I get the following error? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @FilippoSebastio, i just updated and wrapped k as an int in cast it's a string in your data set